# Swift 3: Adjust MessageBubbleSize according to Maximum text length

Tags: ios, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I want to show `senderName` and `timeStamp` in messageBubble. I have searched a lot, and tried various solutions mentioned in `issues` section of **JSQMessagesViewController** Library and on SO.
I tried adjusting width in `sizeForItemAt` but it did not reflect any changes, though it shows changes in height. To be frank I didn't understand how to render `messageBubbleSizeForItem` method or `bubbleSizeCalculator` method, since I don't know Obj-C.

Here, the messageBubble resizes itself according to message text length, but cuts the `senderName` and `timeStamp` text. I have added timeStamp label on `UIImageView`, set constraints for `Leading` and `Top` space. Then added textView above it and set the constraints.

In `cellForItemAt` I called `cell.messageBubbleImageView.addSubview(cell.timeStamp)`. Even though the text is of 2 letters it should show complete `senderName` and `timeStamp` in every bubble. `senderName`, `timeStamp` and `messageText` are dynamic, received from XMPP.
Please help me. Thanks for your time.

[image]